# XAML array issue

Tags: arrays, xaml

I am using the following arrays as parameters to my value converter.  I can't figure why "params2" is passed as an ArrayExtension and "params1" is passed as a simple TextBlock[] array.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="TextBlock" x:Key="params1">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:Constants.MyDir}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>25</TextBlock>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>


<TabItem.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="TextBlock" x:Key="params2">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:Constants.MyDir}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>55</TextBlock>
    </x:Array>
</TabItem.Resources>
```

Image Viewer XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TotalViewer.ImageViewerWindow"        
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TotalViewer"
    Title="ImageViewerWindow" Name="ImageViewerWindow1">

    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="TextBlock" x:Key="params1">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:Constants.MyDir}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>25</TextBlock>
        </x:Array>
   </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=ImageViewerWindow1, Path=ImagePath, 
            Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, 
            ConverterParameter={StaticResource params1}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you tried to see (in converter) whether ArrayExtension.Items contains of two elements you are expecting to have in converter?

Comment: can you post XAML where array passed in converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I kinda gave up for the moment because I need to get this part working.   In the converter, I test if the parameter is either ArrayExtension or TextBlock[].  If it's ArrayExtension, it will get converted to TextBlock[].